How to find MAC address of printers showing offline on the print server?
Is a print server (Windows Server 2022) even logging printer MAC addresses at any point? I searched event log, and used Total Commander's "Find text:" function but no luck yet.
I set printers with static IP and put them in a certain VLAN then set the port on the wall to that VLAN but users tend to unplug the cables and plug the printers in to the wrong port, so they go offline.
If I'd know the MAC of the printers I could find them in my ProCurves (config, and show mac-address) and could adjust the port VLAN.
